# How to alert for every short arrow with strategy in Tradingview

Tags: pine-script

Hello can I please have some help with my code?

I am trying to get an alert only after the strategy produces a short arrow on chart in TradingView. I receive alerts but not just when an arrow is formed. I am not too sure why, but this is my code:

```
strategy("Momentum Strategy", overlay=true)

length = input(12)

price = close

momentum(seria, length) =>
    mom = seria - seria[length]
    mom
mom0 = momentum(price, length)
mom1 = momentum( mom0, 1)

if (mom0 > 0 and mom1 > 0)
    strategy.entry("MomLE", strategy.long, stop=high+syminfo.mintick, comment="MomLE")
//  alert("Check chart", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

else
    strategy.cancel("MomLE")

if (mom0 < 0 and mom1 < 0)
    strategy.entry("MomSE", strategy.short, stop=low-syminfo.mintick, comment="MomSE")
    alert("Check chart", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

else
    strategy.cancel("MomSE")
```

Answer (score 0):

`alert()` will be called whenever it is called. Your if conditions might be `true` while you are already in a trade. In that case, you won't see an extra arrow, but your if check will be `true` and your `alert` function will be called.

Instead, use the `alert_message` argument of the `strategy.entry()` function.

```
if (mom0 > 0 and mom1 > 0)
    strategy.entry("MomLE", strategy.long, stop=high+syminfo.mintick, comment="MomLE", alert_message="Check chart")    
else
    strategy.cancel("MomLE")

if (mom0 < 0 and mom1 < 0)
    strategy.entry("MomSE", strategy.short, stop=low-syminfo.mintick, comment="MomSE", alert_message="Check chart")
else
    strategy.cancel("MomSE")
```